# jQuery .next() doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to use jQuery [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) with a selector, seems that I missed something.

My code:

```
<div>1</div>
<span>2</span>
<div class="dd">3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

```js
$('div').next(".dd").css('color','red');
```

If I change the span to div it works, but this way doesn't!

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I should use [nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) not next

```
$('div').nextAll(".dd").css('color','red');
```

[demo working](http://jsfiddle.net/sssonline2/fm5VR/)